# Mortal Shell: How to get out of seat of infinity area?

Tags: mortal-shell

How to get out of seat of infinity after you killed the boss?

I tried to retrace back, but the last tp leads to a dead end. Explored the whole area, but can't find any other tp within my reach.

I tried to google, but all the walkthroughs rely on the presence of lift near the sister. I don't have this lift, since I've sent it down so it would be easier to run back up every time after death.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer on reddit. There is a pillar, which is normally not interactable and looks redundant, but when the lift is down you can interact with it normally (just like with tp, for example).

[image]